# Move Camera is an order so that the background doesn't move fast

Tags: unity, camera, parallax-scrolling

I have created a game where I am moving my player on a platform. The car moves fine on the platform and the camera follows the car as well. My problem is that I wanted my background to move slowly. I am using a perspective camera and I am moving camera away to create a zoom out effect when my player jumps. Do you suggest I should move my background towards right so that it creates a simple slow effect? As currently it moves very fast.

here is my video demonstration : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xO_mEXo6mNA

Comment: i can't watch the video cause i'm on a work machine, but my first instinct is to move the background further away from the camera. This causes the angular momentum of the background to be less, resulting in a less dramatic parallax effect.

Comment: simply move the background based on the offset of the camera in the x axis and multiply that by a number that is within a certain number range depending on the depth of your camera.

Comment: @Stephan: that sounds like a good answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try tiling your background and adjusting the offset to create an effect of motion. this will allow you to "slow" and "speed up" the movement of the background

here's the tutorial from Unity:
[Link to Unity Tutorial starting at the right spot](https://youtu.be/GtNW9uD94uc?t=913)

[Link to Full Tutorial with code](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/2d-scrolling-backgrounds)

Answer (score 1):

Move the background further away from the camera.

This causes the angular momentum of the background to be less, resulting in a less dramatic parallax effect.